# Magento2 Product Gallery Images

Tags: magento2, product-images

How to add Custom Videos along with Product Gallery Images on Detail Page

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it Magento OOTB functionality
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-video.html

Comment: I have custom extension to upload product videos i need to add my cutom block with product gallery images